# Fetch all results in table where date is approaching within the next 30 days of current date?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am using the following MySQL query to fetch data from my table where records are less than 30 days old.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' AND date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date DESC";
```

however now I have a need to select all results in my table where the date is within the next 30 days of the current date? I am storing my date as DATETIME. Please can someone show me how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CURDATE()` as the lower bound and `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY` as the upper bound of the date range

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}' AND date > CURDATE() AND date =< CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date DESC";
```